# Two columns into one using alternate rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two columns like this:

```
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
```

etc.

I want to get them into one column, with each column's data in alternate rows of the new column like this:

```
A
1
B
2
C
3
D
4
E
5
```

etc.

Comment: You can try to use function for this or use CTE query with combination of substring function

Comment: To get the ordering right so that you get the results in alternate rows, you will need to add a third column to the source table to impose an ordering. Together with the answers below, that should get you the expected output.

Comment: Seems like the main issue here is treating SQL tables as being the same as a spreadsheet. Despite superficial similarities, they're not the same thing. All row values should be closely aligned to a single "thing". Separate rows should be independent. Rows and columns are not interchangable.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `UNION ALL` but here is the `UNPIVOT` alternative:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(letter VARCHAR(10),Id VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Table1(letter ,Id )
SELECT 'A',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E',5 


SELECT [value]
FROM #Table1
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [Column] IN ([Id], [letter])
) UNPVT


DROP TABLE #Table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(Value VARCHAR(10),Id VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Table1(Value ,Id )
SELECT 'A',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E',5 

;WITH _CTE (Name) AS
(
 SELECT Value [Name]
 FROM #Table1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Id [Name]
 FROM #Table1
)
SELECT * FROM _CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is the *data in alternate rows*

```
select col2 
from 
 ( select col1, 1 as flag, col1 from tab
   union all
   select col1, 2,         col2 from tab
 ) as dt
order by col1, flag
```

But why do you try to do this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Col1Name Name,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))) RN 
  FROM TableName
  UNION 
  SELECT Col2Name Name,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)))+1 RN 
  FROM TableName
)
SELECT Name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: That ordering is the best you can do, without a third column to impose ordering. Perhaps you could expand on that?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. but this script will results what op looking for. you could try this with sample data as well. ;)

Comment: Sure sure :) I'm just wanted to point out that `ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))` does arbitrary ordering. It could well change when eg indexes are added/changed. I would type out an answer but seeing as there are already three answers, I just thought maybe you could expand on that.

Comment: @TT. Please help me on it how can expand this ordering `ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))`

Comment: Actually this is more of a suggestion towards the OP. Without a third column that imposes strict ordering, it's harder to guarantee the order of the rows returned. When you have that third column, an `ID` column say, you simply order on that ID column. In the CTE, you would `SELECT Col1Name, Id, <0 or 1> AS alternate_id ... UNION ALL ...` and in the ordering of the final select `ORDER BY Id, alternate_id`.